# Change Current nav item

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to change the nav item in my ASP.Net MVC 4 project. I have found some examples but they dont work with the way the menu in need( See code):

```
  <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/StartMenu/Index" class="current" title="Dashboard">
                    <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
                    Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/StartMenu/Forms" title="Forms Stuff">
                    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
                    Forms Stuff
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: how exactly are you trying to "change the nav item"?

Comment: I need to change the class="current", so then Forms Stuff is pushed, thats the one that is change in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is make sure the last link that was clicked has `class="current"` you can do this

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $("a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
})
```

Comment: Nice. But i can't seem to get it to work. 
'<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function () {
        $("a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    })
</script>' But it is not responing.

Comment: do you have jquery included on your page?

Comment: Yes but all of them is Global. Diffend in the _Layout.cshtml